# What explains the correlation between the slope and intercept?

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients

If $R^2$ explains the variation explained by a model, what explains the correlation between the coefficients given for a slope parameter and an intercept?

I have been thinking of it in two ways:

1. If I could grab the slope and physically move it around so the slope changed, as I moved the right end up or down, the left end would move as well and in theory change the intercept.
2. The intercept could remain fixed but the line could rotate around it, so to speak.

Is there a symbol or a test we conduct to test the correlation between the slope and intercept when it is at certain values? Or would this be pointless?

Comment: What do you mean by "correlation" in this context? You are talking about two coefficients that are estimated together. So is your question about how the estimation of one (the intercept) depends on how you fix the other (slope)? E.g. by imposing constraints?

To what end would you maybe want to test such a thing, maybe this could allow us to suggest something else you could test.

Comment: A hint: in a regression of Y on X with linear functional form, the fitted OLS regression line always passes through the point defined by the respective means of the sample values of Y and X.

Comment: Because the slope and the intercept are parameters of the model, there is no correlation between them: they are just numbers and do not vary.  Yes, the slope and intercept *estimates* may be correlated: but then it makes no sense to test them, because these are estimates, not parameters.